# Android studio 3.2.1 not building new project and color.xml file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why this problem is occurring? I install new Android Studio 3.2.1 and now when creating a new project every time Failed. color.xml file not created correctly and I tried multiple solutions but it is not working. need help...

[image]

Comment: complete comment by -->

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and delete the comments  `?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>`